# C logical or in if

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

I know I'm not very good in C but I thought that I could get this right:

```
if(strlen(type) == 0 || strcmp(type,"in")!=0 || strcmp(type,"out")!=0)
```

`type` comes as a `char*` and I've tested this code with the first part of the condition.It works well.If I have the second part of the condition and my `type` contains `"in"` it's ok but if all three conditions are available,if i input `"out"`,the if isn't skipped.Why's that?

Comment: At any point `type` can be "in", "out" or neither. So whatever happens one of the last 2 conditions will match.

Comment: But if my `type` has `out` shouldn't the last condition be false and so the if will not be executed?

Comment: Yes, but the second condition will be true if `type` is `out`.

Comment: If `type` is "out" the last condition isn't even evaluated because the previous one will match.

Comment: 'or' means any condition true.  You might want && - and here.

Comment: @MateiMarius -  Don't put "solved" in the title. That's not how this works. Ask the one who explained it to put it as an answer then accept, or failing a response, you can post it as an answer yourself and check the community wiki button explaining it was converted from a comment.

Comment: @cnicutar Am I correct in my answer, i have request to you to please check my answer.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Looks ok on a cursory look. Might want to expand on how the OP can fix it.

Comment: @cnicutar thanks for respond. can you please check once more Sorry for bothering but its bit tricky..

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I'm not sure you need the flag thing (and did you actually mean `flag = 'x'` with a single `=` ?). I would have done it with a sequence of `if else if`. Still the OP probably got it so, whatever works.

Comment: @MateiMarius read updated answer get a code from link execute it try to understand what I did and if any confusion/doubt let me know.

Comment: No,I got it from the first version,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code:

```
if(strlen(type) == 0 || strcmp(type,"in")!=0 || strcmp(type,"out")!=0){
    " your code-1"
}
else{
    " your code-2"
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if(strlen(type) == 0 ){
    " your code-1"
}
else{
  if(strcmp(type,"in")!=0){
      " your code-1"   
  }
  else{
      if(strcmp(type,"out")!=0){
            " your code-1"   
      }
      else{
            " your code-2"
      }
  }
}
```

Point is if you have *first* `if()` executes if string `type` have something, then else never executes. Because a empty string(*in else part*) can't be equals to `"in"` or `"out"`. So you always have choice to execute "code-1" if string is *not empty* and nothing to executes if string is empty (*that is length = 0*).

Edit:

I think you wants something like if `type` string is "in" then execute "code-1" if type is "out" then execute second code-2. like:

```
if(strlen(type) == 0 ){

}
else{
  if(strcmp(type,"in")!=0){
      " your code-1"   
  }
  else{
      if(strcmp(type,"out")!=0){
            " your code-2"   
      }
  }
}
```

you can do like:

```
flag = 'o';// this will save string comparison  again
if(strlen(type) == 0 || strcmp(type,"in")==0 || 
                       strcmp(type,"out")!=0 && !(flag='?')){
   "code-1"
}
else{
       if(flag=='o'){ //no strcmp needed
          "code-2"
       }
}
```

[Here I posted a Code](http://codepad.org/zZDdfXN3) based on my logic and it run as:

```
:~$ ./a.out 
Enter string: in
in 
:~$ ./a.out 
Enter string: out
out 
:~$ ./a.out 
Enter string: xx
:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

The branch will be taken if `type` is empty, or if `type` contains either "in" or "out".

Given the expression `a || b`, the following are true:

- Operands are evaluated left-to-right, meaning `a` is evaluated first;
- if `a` evaluates to non-zero (true), then the entire expression evaluates to true, and `b` *is not evaluated*;
- if `a` evaluates to zero (false), then `b` is evaluated;
- if both `a` and `b` evaluate to zero (false), then the entire expression evaluates to false; otherwise, the expression evaluates to true;

So if `type` contains the string "out", then

- `strlen(type) == 0` evaluates to `false`, meaning we evaluate
- `strcmp(type, "in") != 0`, which evaluates to `false`, meaning we evaluate
- `strcmp(type, "out") != 0`, which evaluates to `true`, so
- the branch is taken

Based on what you say you're expecting, it sounds like you got the sense of the last test wrong, and that you really want

```
if( strlen( type ) == 0 || 
    strcmp( type, "in" ) != 0 || 
    strcmp( type, "out" ) == 0 )
{                      // ^^ note operator
  ...
}
```

This will enter the branch if `type` is empty, if `type` contains "in", or if `type` *doesn't* contain "out".