# Readable conditional logic without unnecessary execution?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make the below code both readable and performant.  I want to avoid any unnecessary call to `getFlagB()` while also not repeating anything.  Below I have written two methods, each which satisfies exactly one of these criteria.

Assume `getFlagB()` cannot be altered in any way.  Is there a way to meet both these requirements simultaneously in C, without creating additional flags?

```
// Method 1 - doesn't repeat code blocks but calls getFlagB even when it may not need to
void foo(int flagA)
{
    int flagB;
    getFlagB(&flagB);

    if(flagA & flagB)
    {
        // Code block 0
    }
    else
    {
        // Code block 1
    }
}

// Method 2 - doesn't no extra call to getFlagB, but repeats code block 1
void foo(int flagA)
{
    int flagB;

    if(flagA)
    {
        getFlagB(&flagB);
        if(flagB)
        {
            // Code block 0
        }
        else
        {
            // Code block 1
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Code block 1
    }
}
```

Comment: refactor so getFlagB returns a value then use `if (flagA && getFlagB())`

Comment: From the question: "Assume getFlagB() cannot be altered in any way."

Comment: Wrap getFlagB in another method `int myGetFlagB() { int b; getFlagB(&b); return b; }`

Comment: Read this [C logical or in if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885715/c-logical-or-in-if/15886376#15886376) may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the condition explicitly before the `if`.

```
_Bool condition = flagA;

if ( flagA ) { /* First decide what to do. */
    _Bool flagB;
    GetFlagB( & flagB );

    condition = flagA && flagB; /* Prefer && over &. */
}

if ( condition ) { /* Then do it. */
    Code1();
} else {
    Code2();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
void foo(int flagA)
{
    int flagB;

    if(flagA)
    {
        getFlagB(&flagB);
        if(flagB)
        {
            // Code block 0
            return ;
        }
    }
  // code block 1
}
```

Comment: Maybe, because you didn't realize, that your code executes both blocks in sequence when the condition is true, which is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: Oh, yes, I take back everything I said and say the opposite is true. Sorry, somehow the `return` had escaped my notice :-( By the way, it was not I who first downvoted this answer, I just saw your comment and thought, I saw the reason. Maybe I did, and the other guy also overlooked the `return`, but of course I don't know.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, it's a valid answer to my incomplete question.  I should have put another code block after the if/else condition that must get executed afterward.  My bad, I should have phrase it better.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap `getFlagB()` in another method, then let the compiler sort it out for you.

```
int myGetFlagB() { int b; getFlagB(&b); return b; }

void foo(int flagA)
{
    /* note: assume you mean && and not &, otherwise there is no way
     * to short circuit - you always need to call getFlagB for a
     * bitwise AND.
     */
    if(flagA && myGetFlagB())
    {
        // Code block 0
    }
    else
    {
        // Code block 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, since the comma operator denotes a sequence point, you could use: `if (flagA && (getFlagB(&flagB), flagB)) ...`.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot definitively say anything because I have not seen any actual code but it seems to me the flagA is irrelevant and can be ignored. While flagB must be evaluated because it is relevant and causes the code to change.

```
void foo()
{
    getFlagB(&flagB)
    if(flagB)
    {
        //Code 1
    }
    else
    {
         //Code 0
    }
}
```

But I am assuming that you do not have an unnecessary flag in your program. So I would recommend doing the seconded one it is more efficient and elegant even thought it does not seem that way.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

You can also do the following, so long as flagB is initialized to 0. This avoids a bug in the code I posted earlier that assumes the flags aren't modified inside code block 0, which can cause both code blocks 0 and 1 to execute. I'd recommend this new one only because you may at some point want to modify the flags inside foo():

```
int flagB = 0;

if (flagA)
    getFlagB(&flagB);

if (flagA && flagB) {
    // code block 0
} else {
    // code block 1
}
```

Yes, flagA is tested twice. You have a ternary condition, but you're asking for a binary set of outcomes. Without using sequence points as one person mentioned, you must test twice or duplicate code or unnecessarily call a function or add extra function call overhead if flagA happens to be set.

They're all valid solutions IMHO. It is just a matter of how readable and how well performing you want the code to be, not to mention avoiding code duplication... Nobody likes that! :-)

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not want to either encapsulate the getFlagB call or split your if, you can abuse the comma operator:

```
if(flagA && (getFlagB(&flagB), flagB)) {
```

Even though it does not look nice, it does precisely what you want.

Comment: From the question : "I'm trying to make the below code both _readable_ and performant."

Comment: +1. Readability goes out the window when defining functions with `void` return type and gratuitous return-by-reference.